# How do you unnest JSON, column with a list of dict in a dataframe to a new Dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe, `df_object` that has a column that contains a list of dict items.

| ObjectID | research |
| --- | --- |
| 392 | {'researchID': '10003', 'research.type': 'x-ray', 'research.date': '2004'}, {'researchID': '10006', 'research.type': 'document', 'research.date': '2005' |
| 394 | {'researchID': '10012', 'research.type': 'x-ray', 'research.date': '2005'} |

My goal is to have a new dataframe from the research column, that includes the ObjectID, but uses the researchID as the index:

| researchID (index) | ObjectID | research.type | research.date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10003 | 392 | x-ray | 2004 |
| 10006 | 392 | document | 2005 |
| 10012 | 394 | x-ray | 2005 |

When I use this code: `df = pd.DataFrame(df_object['research'][392])`
the columns are correct and it looks like this:

| researchID (index) | ObjectID | research.type | research.date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10003 | 392 | x-ray | 2004 |
| 10006 | 392 | document | 2005 |

The issue is that I don't know how to add the rest of the objectID data on. I thought I could iterate all the rows in df_object and append the rows but wasn't sure if that's the best way because I read that you shouldn't keep appending hundreds of rows to dataframes like that because it's slow.

When I tried `df = pd.DataFrame(df_object['research'])`, then the index stays on ObjectID and it's nested.

I tried a few flatten JSON functions from around StackOverflow, but I kept getting errors and I'm not sure if that's what I needed to be searching for.

**ADDED**
Output from: `df_object.head(2).to_dict()`

```
{'research': {392: [{'researchID': '10003', 'research.type': ['x-ray'], 'research.date': '2004'},{'researchID': '10006', 'research.type': 'document', 'research.date': '2005'}], 393: {'researchID': '10012', 'research.type': 'x-ray', 'research.date': '2005'}}
```

Comment: Can you provide the constructor to your dataframe. `df.head().to_dict()`?

Comment: Where would I add this? sorry I'm a bit confused

Comment: Add the output of `df.head().to_dict()` to your question so we can reproduce your dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that in `research` column you have list of dict items (as you stated in your question). Then:

```py
df = df.explode("research")
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("research").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ObjectID researchID research.type research.date
0       392      10003         x-ray          2004
0       392      10006      document          2005
1       394      10012         x-ray          2005
```

---

To set `researchID` as index:

```py
print(df.set_index("researchID"))
```

Prints:

```
            ObjectID research.type research.date
researchID                                      
10003            392         x-ray          2004
10006            392      document          2005
10012            394         x-ray          2005
```